# Restrictive and Nonrestrictive Elements

Tags: punctuation

My mother, Theresa; my brother, Frank; and my sister, Danielle, are going to the meeting. (In this sentence I have one mother, one brother, and one sister.) The sentence is cluttered with punctuation, albeit correct I think.

The Associated Press replied and said to strictly use commas (which appear wrong):

> My mother, Theresa, my brother, Frank, and my sister, Danielle, are going to the meeting.

They even said that, in the inverted construction, to do this (which looks worse):

> Theresa, my mother, Frank, my brother, and Danielle, my sister, are going to the meeting.

Can we get away with removing all the punctuation and punctuate that same sentence thusly?

> My mother Theresa, my brother Frank and my sister Danielle are going to the meeting. (In this sentence I have one mother, one brother, and one sister.)

Thank you.

Comment: "Theresa, my mother, Frank, my brother, and Danielle, my sister, are going to the meeting." I think we'd be forced (for clarity) to use semicolons, do you? E.g., "Theresa, my mother; Frank, my brother; and Danielle, my sister, are going to the meeting." But we'd use a comma--not a semicolon--after "my sister", agreed?

Comment: At any rate, which presented versions would you accept? If you don't support any of them, how'd you punctuate each of these? Thank you.

Comment: You are wrong with your use of the semicolons; the AP is right to remove them and replace them with commas.  As for the inverted construction, it puts the emphasis on the names, which I think is fine. You could get away without using their inverted construction suggestion, as long as you use the commas.  Your use of the semicolon is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, but this inverted construction (with just the commas) is correct? Theresa, my mother, Frank, my brother, and Danielle, my sister, are going to the meeting.

Comment: @Soylent Green The use of the semicolon as a 'super-comma' is becoming more acceptable (but since you don't give endorsement for your dogma, neither will I). So I could well say "You are wrong with your prescriptive 'You are wrong with your use of the semicolons' ". But obviously the AP is old-school. (FWIW, I'd use OP's final suggestion here.)

Comment: Getting confused. So these are correct per AP's guidance? Again, one mother, one brother and one sister. No ambiguity (with just the commas) in these two sentences?

(1) "My mother, Theresa, my brother, Frank, and my sister, Danielle, are going to the meeting." 

(2) "Theresa, my mother, Frank, my brother, and Danielle, my sister, are going to the meeting." 

Thanks.

Comment: Whippoorwill: I wouldn't label your first version 'ungrammatical' (or 'wrongly punctuated' for those who like to preserve distinctions), but as you yourself say, it's stylistically poor. Some (perhaps many) people _would_ object to the 'super-comma' usage of the semicolon. Since the AP seems to have clout with you, it's best not to argue with them. They probably still require 'It is I'. I'd try them with Theresa (my mother), Frank (my brother) and Danielle (my sister) are going to the meeting. I myself would not wish to use their suggested version. But they're not _my_ bosses.

Comment: Edwin, I wholeheartedly concur that your revision—with the parentheses—is much better and provides 'crystal-clear' disambiguation.

Comment: I've gone and found an ['authority'](http://www.englishclub.com/writing/punctuation-semi-colon.htm) disagreeing with AP: **Use a semi-colon as a kind of "super comma".** When we have a list of items, we usually separate the items with commas. If the list is complicated, we may prefer to use semi-colons in some cases.

ABC Investments has offices in five locations: Kensington, London; Brighton & Hove; and Oxford, Cambridge and Manchester. // 

Rental cars must be returned on time; with a full tank of petrol; in undamaged condition; and at the same location as they were collected from.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13001/discussion-between-whippoorwill-and-edwin-ashworth)

Comment: .................When?

Comment: Grammatically, your last example is fine: *"My mother Theresa, my brother Frank, and my sister Danielle are going to the meeting."* But be aware that you may have to rewrite it for those publishers that have style guides which might require something else. (Though, I do find it peculiar that you refer to your mother by first name.)

Answer (score 1):

The construction *my brother Frank* is common enough that it would probably appear less awkward than using semicolons as second-level commas. So I would go with your last construction:

> My mother Theresa, my brother Frank, and my sister Danielle are going to the meeting.

with the noticeable difference of putting a comma before the "and". ;-)

Comment: Thanks, everyone. This is the best forum out there. You people are brilliant. I'm just learning ... not really good at this stuff (as you can readily decipher).

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a forum, but we appreciate the endorsement anyway :P